# Openshift support to customers of premium packages

Tags: openshift

I signed up for a silver package from Openshift. Is there any additional (openshift-specific issues) support to premium package customers in addition to questions posted at Stackover?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

You can log a support ticket at http://access.redhat.com if you have a silver account (https://www.openshift.com/support right side of page).  Free and Bronze users get community support.